# How to access DI repository from a different machine

Tags: pentaho

Can someone please suggest me how to centrally store DB connections and jobs in DI repository

I installed s/w on 2 machines. On one machine I have enabled the Kettle DI repository but when I try to access the same from the other m/c, I am not able to access

Can someone suggest me any good tutorial or video etc ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Repository connection definitions are stored in your .kettle file. This is by default in your user profile directory. To share the same definitions among a group of users on the same machine, move the kettle home directory to a shared location and set the KETTLE_HOME environment variable to reflect that location.

Then copy that .kettle file to all installations that need to share the repositories.